# xpath - how to union queries with priority of query

Tags: xpath, union, multiple-conditions

I want to combine 3 queries with union operator "|" which is working fine, 
but I want to set priority per every query, so for example if first query will bring result then it needs to be node[0]

example : //div[@class='class1'] | //div[@class='class2'] | //div[@class='class3']

so if string have more than 1 query matches that it needs to follow some priority or even better do not bring any results on other queries if one before have some matches
Please help
Thank You

Comment: maybe add the xpath query to the other two xpaths? so that the other two xpath rely on the previous xpath.. example: `//div[@class='class1'] | //div[@class='class1']/following-sibling::div[@class='class2']` you have to be creative though

Comment: Thats a bit opposite, i need "if class1 doesnt exist than search for class2"

Comment: Please specify which version of XPath. If this is XPath 1.0, you may be out of luck.

Comment: I am using it with Php, not sure if php working with xpath 1.0 or 2.0

Comment: then `//div[@class='class1'] | //body[not(div[@class='class1'])]/div[@class='class2'] | //body[not(div[@class='class1'] and not(div[@class='class2']))]/div[@class='class3']` if class1 exists, then 2nd and 3rd xpath will result to nothing, if class 2 exists then 3rd xpath will result to nothing..as I said before, you have to be creative..

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one node in the result, then the usual approach (assuming XPath 2.0 or higher) is:

```
(//div[@class='class1'], //div[@class='class2'], //div[@class='class3'])[1]
```

If there might be several nodes with @class='class1', and you want all of them, and you only want nodes with @class='class2' if there are none with @class='class1', then it's a bit more difficult. But before we go any further, you need to tell us which version of XPath you are using.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am using it with php, so i think its version 1.x

Comment: Then I think you're going to have to do some of the work in the PHP code, issuing multiple XPath requests until one of them selects something. (Unless of course you can move to Saxon/C which provides XPath 3.0 to PHP users...)

Answer (score 0):

`//div[@class='class1'] | //body[not(div[@class='class1'])]/div[@class='class2'] | //body[not(div[@class='class1'] and not(div[@class='class2']))]/div[@class='class3']`

if class1 exists, then 2nd and 3rd xpath will result to nothing, if class 2 exists then 3rd xpath will result to nothing..

that's the idea, but you have to work on it further...be creative my man.