# TSQL XPath for nodes with different names

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

In SQL Server 2008 (yes, I know) how do you write an XPath to find nodes with different names?

For example, if I had either of the following XML...

```
DECLARE @XML XML = '<data><id>1</id><id>2</id></data>'
or...
DECLARE @XML XML = '<d><i>1</i><i>2</i></d>'
```

I can write the following which will work for the first XML, but wouldn't work for the second XML.

```
SELECT X.value('.','int') FROM @XML.nodes('/data/id') AS X(X)
```

I was going to use a union `(/data/id | /d/i)` but SQL Server apparently doesn't support unions.

The simple solution is to do the following...

```
SELECT X.value('.','int') FROM @XML.nodes('/data/id') AS X(X)
UNION
SELECT X.value('.','int') FROM @XML.nodes('/d/i') AS X(X)
```

... but I would prefer it if there was a single XPath solution instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42689648/930393) (which is for general XPath, not SQL based) and it has given me the solution.

Use the `,` character and wrap in brackets...

```
SELECT X.value('text()[1]','int') FROM @XML.nodes('(/data/id,/d/i)') AS X(X)
```

(Note, I've also updated the `'.'` to be `'text()[1]'` as per the suggestion by @YitzhakKhabinsky)

Comment: `SELECT X.value('text()[1]','int')  ...` would be even faster.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky - although I'm struggling to figure out what the `nodes` XPath would be?  If I use `//*` it return 3 rows including `NULL`

Comment: @Yitzhak - sorry, I think I was getting confused... you're suggesting simply changing the `.` to `text()[1]`.  Is that really that much faster than just using `.`?  If so, there's a LOT of places I could probably do with updating, as I used it very, very regularly

Comment: That's correct. It is always a good idea for performance reasons to use `text()` when dealing with XML elements in SQL Server.

Comment: Please upvote my suggestion: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/153a9604-7025-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Comment: Fair enough @Yitzhak, I will use that, and try and remember to use it in the future. Many thanks for your time :-)